Bash `sed` regex grouping
I'm trying to turn a line like this to using sed I'm not really good with regex and I'm looking for some help with the sed command.
/Application/Lockscreen/ @smiths
/Application/BlueLock/ @egoists

to
path: */Application/Lockscreen/* @smiths
path: */Application/BlueLock/* @egoists


How about awk? Assuming spaces separate the columns: awk '{print "path: *" $1 "*", $2}'

I'd do this, using any sed, so it works even if the string in the middle contains spaces or @s:
$ sed 's/\(.*\)\( @[^@]*\)/path: *\1*\2/' file
path: */Application/Lockscreen/* @smiths
path: */Application/BlueLock/* @egoists


$ echo '/Application/Foo @Bar/ @whatever' | sed 's/\(.*\)\( @[^@]*\)/path: *\1*\2/'
path: */Application/Foo @Bar/* @whatever

It just relies on the string at the end not containing multiple @s.
